# How to call a Python function from an act_window in OpenERP7?

Tags: python, xml, action, odoo, openerp-7

I added a new option to the menu **More**, at the top side of the screen (**tree** view). To do that, I did an `act_window` in XML:

```
<act_window name="Invite partners to an event"
     res_model="mail.compose.message"
     src_model="event.registration"
     view_mode="form"
     multi="True"
     target="new"
     id="invite_partner_to_event"/>
```

Everything works OK, I can select rows of the tree view of `event.registration`, click on **More**, and mi option ***Invite partners to an event*** appears. When I click on this, the form view of the model `mail.compose.message` is opened in a pop-up, which is exactly what I want.

Now my problem: I'd like to perform a Python function when I click on my option, (and the user mustn't notice that). I.E.: the user won't be able to feel the difference, but I will be modifying several things in the backend through that function.

¿How could I manage this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a button it would work like this and I suspect you can declare the option underneath More the same way
your XML

```
<button name="name_of_your_method_here" string="Invite partners" type="object"/>
```

your Python:

```
def name_of_your_method_here(self,cr,uid,ids,context=None):
 #your functionality here
 return True
```

you could also make the pythoncode open the view:

```
def name_of_your_method_here(self,cr,uid,ids,context=None):
 #your functionality here
 return {
    'name' : 'The name of your view',
    'res_model' : 'name_of_the_model',
    'view_mode': 'form',
    'view_type' : 'form',        
    'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
    'target': 'new',
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @programme! But if I use a normal button, the option won't be shown in the dropdown of More.

Comment: So correct me if I'm wrong. You want to open an method when you open the view. or do you want it to happen before the view opens?

Answer (score 0):

i found the method to call python code in more item:

```
 <record id="action_confirm_all_server" model="ir.actions.server">
        <field name="name">Approve</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="model_overtime_request"/>
        <field name="state">code</field>
        <field name="code">action = obj.action_confirm_all(context=context)</field>
    </record>

     <record id="ir_values_more_action_confirm" model="ir.values">
        <field eval="'client_action_multi'" name="key2"/>
        <field eval="'overtime.request'" name="model"/>
        <field name="name">Approve</field>
        <field eval="'ir.actions.server,%d'%action_confirm_all_server" name="value"/>
    </record>
```

python code:

```
    def action_confirm_all(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    if context is None: context = {}
    _logger.info('server call')
    return {
    }
```